# How to find x-value of highest peak in histogram?

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

How to save x-value of highest peak in histogram into variable? Thank you
[image]

Comment: [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) returns the location in the second output argument.

Comment: I have histogram `h=histogram(file,50);` with file of one columns - x values. What variable is in y-axis - the count in bins? I don't know what is the argument of max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fileID = fopen('q65.txt','r');
formatSpec = '%f';
file = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec);

h = histogram(file,50);
%Find index of maximum
[~, index]= max(h.Values);

delta = h.BinLimits(2)-h.BinLimits(1);
% find the range for a single bin
slot = delta./h.NumBins;

%location = minimum y + (index of maxmium)*slot 
lb = h.BinLimits(1) + (index-1)*slot;
ub = h.BinLimits(1) + (index)*slot;

location = [lb, ub]
```

Location is a **range**, not a fixed number

## A simple one

```
fileID = fopen('q65.txt','r');
formatSpec = '%f';
file = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec);
h = histogram(file,50);
%Find index of maximum
[~, index]= max(h.Values);
lb = h.BinEdges(index);
ub = h.BinEdges(index+1);
location = [lb, ub]
```

Comment: I don't know why it shows different numbers than the histogram

Comment: a more simple one gives another result, also differerent from the graph

Comment: upload your ```file``` document, I will check it for you

Comment: http://leteckaposta.cz/187079771 in this way or could we go to discussion? The maximum peak is 0,42 - 0,43

Comment: I got ```location = [0.4022  , 0.4233]```

Comment: @LukášAltman I updated my answer, copy it exactly into your matlab and check the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193532/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

```
[Y,X] = max(h);
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: It gives an error: Error using max
Invalid data type. First argument must be numeric or logical.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the highest peak in histogram

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.2, 2.1, 3.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.5, 4.9, 5.3])
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=7, range=[0, 7])
max_hist = max(hist)
max_hist_idx = np.where(hist == max_hist)[0][0]
max_hist_mean = (bin_edges[max_hist_idx] + bin_edges[max_hist_idx + 1]) / 2
print(f'Maximum value= {max_hist_mean:.1f}')
```